# Footer not showing up

Tags: html, css, footer

For some reason, my footer is not showing up at the bottom of the page and it doesn't display the white background color at all, it just shows the navbar.

```css
.mainFooter {
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%; 
 height:50px; 
 background:#FFC; 
 z-index:1;  
}
```

```html
*<footer class="mainFooter">
<nav><ul>
        <li><a href="../$">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="../$">About</a></li>
   </ul></nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: What is your preferred output? I saw in JSfiddle. I cannot find what your require.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/ffhroz54/

Comment: What white background? The CSS defines the background as yellow. Please provide enough code that replicates the problem.

Comment: #FFC is a very light yellow. #FFF is white.

Answer (score -1):

Your footer **is** showing - you just got the wrong color. You use `#FFC` - which is a light yellow. If you want white, use `#FFF`.

This might help you understand Hex Color Codes:

> http://www.codeconquest.com/hex-color-codes/

Edit: Read

> [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?rq=1)

Comment: I am aware that the color isn't white, but that's really not the issue :D ; 
I simply cannot display the footer, the two navs just stick to the header.

Comment: Then your question needs heavy reworking. If your problem is the wrong position of your footer, then SAY SO. If I had to guess I'd bet you do not understand how absolute positioning works.

Comment: To be fair the first sentence of the question is "my footer is not showing up at the bottom of the page." But I agree that it's impossible to give an answer without seeing something that replicates the problem.

Comment: And it's also extremely misleading for he is using yellow, but mentions white background not showing.